# What is the Addr# type, and how can I use it?

Tags: haskell, primitive-types

I've recently been looking around at various Haskell quirks, like unboxed types and whatnot, when I discovered the `Addr#` type.

The [`GHC.Prim`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#g:10) package describes it as so:

> An arbitrary machine address assumed to point outside the garbage-collected heap.

And that means not much to me.

Furthermore, I keep finding functions like this that use the type:

```
readIntOffAddr# :: Addr# -> Int# -> State# s -> (#State# s, Int##)
```

What is this type? What can I do with it? Why is it necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent* C code would be:

```
long readIntOffAddr(long *ptr, long offset) {
    return ptr[offset];
}
```

`Addr#` is just like `void *`. The function has an `IO`-like signature because it is not "pure". Multiple calls to the function may return different values (obviously).

<sub>* **Update (2018):** I just learned that equating C's `int` type with Haskells `Int#` type is wrong. So I changed `int` to `long` in the above code snippet. This is also (maybe) not 100% correct, but at least it is true for all GHC implementations that I have seen. In GHC versions 6-8 (haven't checked others), `Int#` is 32 bit wide on 32-bit platforms and 64 bit wide on 64-bit platforms. This matches the behaviour of GCC for `long` for all C/C++ implementations on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms that I am aware of, so I think equating `Int#` with `long` is a good first approximation. No one noticed this minor inaccuracy in the last 3 years (or cared enough to edit/comment). I doubt that there is any Haskell/Platform/C combination where `HsInt` != `long` where the Haskell implementation has a `readIntOffAddr#` function.. please prove me wrong.</sub>

Comment: yes, I only said `IO`-like, because the whole `IO`-monad is built around the concept of passing `State#` values around. If you look at the implementation of the `IO` monad in GHC, you will see that it is defined as `newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))` where the right-hand-side `State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #)` looks really similar to `State# s -> (# State# s, a #)`. So, the `readIntOffAddr#` function can easily be lifted to the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 10):

As a complement to Michael's answer:

`Addr#` is the unboxed type underlying a `Ptr a` in the same way that `Int#` is the unboxed type underlying an `Int`. Its contents are presumably to be interpreted as a machine address, though as far as the compiler and GC are concerned it is just another integral type (of whatever size pointers are on the system in question). Since it is an arbitrary machine address and not a GC-managed pointer, it should presumably not point into the Haskell heap because the addresses of Haskell heap objects are not stable as viewed from the level of Haskell (a GC could occur at any point in your program, and then whatever object your `Addr#` pointed at now lives elsewhere, or nowhere at all).

Normally a `Ptr a`/`Addr#` will contain a pointer returned from `malloc`/`mmap`/etc., or a pointer to a C global variable, or in general any sort of thing that a pointer might sensibly point to in a C program. You would normally use `readIntOffAddr#` when interfacing with a C function that returns or modifies the contents of a passed `HsInt *`. (Well, you wouldn't use it directly, you'd use `Int`'s `peekElemOff` `Storable` method which I presume is implemented in terms of `readIntOffAddr#`, or you would use an even higher-level function like `peekArray`).

Comment: This clarified it for me. Thanks.